# How to store single result from XPath Extractor

Tags: regex, jmeter, jmeter-3.2

I have a HTTP request that return the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
       <soapenv:Body>
          <NS1:obterAtividadesResponse xmlns:NS1="http://www.multiplan.com.br/APL/CLIE/SN/BPM/v1">
             <atividades>
                <atividade>
                   <instancia>
                      <idInstancia>2024</idInstancia>
                   </instancia>
                   <idAtividade>12887</idAtividade>
                   <nomeProcesso>Nota Fiscal ao Pagamento - Resumido</nomeProcesso>
                   <nomeAtividade>Aprovar Pagamento</nomeAtividade>
                   <statusAtividade>Received</statusAtividade>
                   <statusInstancia>Active</statusInstancia>
                   <dataLimite>2017-09-13T16:08:44.994+00:00</dataLimite>
                   <snapshot>76</snapshot>
                   <dadosNegocio>
                      <name>pedido</name>
                      <value>4500529987</value>
                   </dadosNegocio>
                </atividade>
             </atividades>
          </NS1:obterAtividadesResponse>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

I'm trying to extract the idAtividade content with XPath Extractor and save the result on atividadeId variable, but it's saving it's value on atividadeId_1 as you can see in the debug sampler result below:

```
atividadeId=
atividadeId_1=12887
atividadeId_matchNr=1
```

I'm using the following xpath query:

```
//atividades/atividade/idAtividade/text()
```

[image]

Is there a way to make it work as I need it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should check `Return entire XPath fragment instead of text content?` checkbox.

It will them take the only text using your expression. See [manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor).

Also consider using Regular Expression Extractor.

Comment: I've got the same result (array) insted of only one value. Any other thing to try?

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than one `atividade` instance in response you can use the following XPath expression to get the first match:

```
//atividades/atividade[1]/idAtividade/text()
```

Or alternatively you can select `idAtividade` node value where `nomeAtividade` equals to `Aprovar Pagamento` with something like:

```
//atividades/atividade[nomeAtividade/text()='Aprovar Pagamento']/idAtividade
```

However given you have only one `atividade` instance your expression should work fine, you can test it using ["XPath Tester" mode of the View Results Tree listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script).

[image: JMeter Xpath Tester]

See [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) and [XPath Language Reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) for comprehensive information on XPath syntax, axes, functions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, my test had an BeanShell Preprocessor setting the value of atividadeId variable to blank and I didn't know it was being executing after each sampler.